# Combine elements of array of objects using a separator

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is a simple problem with a number of simple solutions, and I'm trying to figure out which is best. I would like a solution which is terse and readable.

Here's the issue. I have an array of objects, and I want to combine several of the object members into pipe separated strings. As an example for this data:

```
[
    {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2
    },
    {
        foo: 10,
        bar: 20
    }
]
```

I want to be able to create strings like this:

```
foo = "1|10";
bar = "2|20";
```

If the items were stored in separate arrays, this would be as simple as using Array.join.

Here's my current solution:

```
var foo = "";
var bar = "";

var firstItem = obj.splice(0,1)[0];
foo = firstItem.foo.toString();
bar = firstItem.bar.toString();

obj.forEach(function (item) {
    foo += "|" + item.foo.toString();
    bar += "|" + item.bar.toString();
​});
```

I also considered the following solution using Array.reduce, but browser support for this is still lacking. I am using Prototype, and [it's Array.reduce](http://prototypejs.org/api/array/reduce) is unfortunately a completely different function than the [native JS implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
var strings = obj.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return {
        a.foo.toString() + "|" + b.foo.toString(),
        a.bar.toString() + "|" + b.bar.toString()
    };
});

// value of strings is now:
// {
//     foo: "1|10",
//     bar: "2|20"
// }
```

Are there any more elegant ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function propsArrayJoin(arr, prop, glue) {
  var results = [];
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    results.push(item[prop].toString());
​ });
  return results.join(glue);
}

obj = [
    {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2
    },
    {
        foo: 10,
        bar: 20
    }
];

foo = propsArrayJoin(obj, 'foo', '|');
bar = propsArrayJoin(obj, 'bar', '|');
```

Comment: That would work, and it makes sense. I don't really like the overhead of creating a second array, though. I'll definitely accept this answer if no one comes up with anything better.

Comment: about the other array, well, you skip the need of the 1st (or remove last '|') that solution has the same complexity as other concatenating the parts, also (for me :) ) it reads better, 1-get all parts, 2-join them with a glue.